Why does C# allow variable scope to extend throughout a block regardless of declaration order?
I am reading a book titled C#10 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari OReilly. When describing local variables, the book says the following:
int x; 

{ 
    int y; 
    int x; // Error - x already defined 
} 

{ 
    int y; // OK - y not in scope 
} 

Console.Write (y); // Error - y is out of scope 


A variable’s scope extends in both directions throughout its code
block. This means that if we moved the initial declaration of x in
this example to the bottom of the method, we’d get the same error.
This is in contrast to C++ and is somewhat peculiar, given that it’s
not legal to refer to a variable or constant before it’s declared.

Chapter 2 of C#10 in a Nutshell


Could someone please explain what this means?

What kind of answer are you looking for? "Why" questions are quite unclear. Please be specific about what you are looking for.

To begin with, I would just want to know what the text quoted from the book means. I know the very basic stuff about variable scopes, but I don't get what the quoted paragraph means.

Could you please explain declaration space and scope? I directly quoted the code and the paragraph from the book, so I am not sure of any ambiguities or wrong conflations.

A { } pair encloses a new "scope", a block where a certain variable is valid.
Both y's are declared in sibling scopes. They will not interfere with each other. Also they will not be available in a parent scope - that's why the Console.WriteLine fails.
However, one x is defined in the "parent" scope and another in a child scope. This child declaration clashes with the one declared in the parent scope. And this would even be the case when you move the "parent" int x to the end of the block, even though it is then not valid to use it earlier.
{
    int x; // Error - x already defined 
}

int x;


Copying in comments:
Q: So why doesn't it allow us to declare a new int x inside the brackets?
My A: If you have different x's at both child and parent level, you cannot use the parent-x from within the child level. My guess is that to prevent that issue, the compiler just forbids shadowing a higher-level declaration.

"And this would even be the case when you move the "parent" int x to the end of the block, even though it is then not valid to use it earlier."
Do you mean the following by the above statement?
{     int y;      int x;  }
int x; // Error - x already defined
(I think not but I cannot come up with another interpretation.) If this is the case, shouldn't this be valid since the scope of the first code block ends and the second int x is out of the scope of the first int x?

@aim correct, but the error is still at the inner int x

Alright, thanks a lot. Could you please explain why this is so? Why does the scope of the int x declared outside the brackets interfere with the one declared inside? The confusing part is we wouldn't be able to do the following (use x before it is declared):
`{ Console.Write(x); }
int x = 5;`
So why doesn't it allow us to declare a new int x inside the brackets?

If you have different x's at both child and parent level, you cannot use the parent-x from within the child level. My guess is that to prevent that issue, the compiler just forbids shadowing a higher-level declaration
